# What is the name of the sqoop oracle buit in connector jar file?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

In lib folder of the Sqoop home directory, I couldn't find any built in connector name related to oracle. Is Ojdbc jar itself acts as a connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "build in" connector. Use must have the "ojdbc6" or "ojdbc7" jar file in the "lib" directory of the sqoop-client.

```
$ ls /usr/hdp/current/sqoop-client/lib/
ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar          commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar         jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar        opencsv-2.3.jar             parquet-generator-1.4.1.jar
ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar     commons-logging-1.1.1.jar      kite-data-core-1.0.0.jar             paranamer-2.7.jar           parquet-hadoop-1.4.1.jar
avro-1.8.0.jar                 hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar            kite-data-hive-1.0.0.jar             parquet-avro-1.4.1.jar      parquet-jackson-1.4.1.jar
avro-mapred-1.8.0-hadoop2.jar  jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar  kite-data-mapreduce-1.0.0.jar        parquet-column-1.4.1.jar    slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar          jackson-core-2.3.1.jar         kite-hadoop-compatibility-1.0.0.jar  parquet-common-1.4.1.jar    snappy-java-1.1.1.3.jar
commons-compress-1.8.1.jar     jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar    mysql-connector-java.jar             parquet-encoding-1.4.1.jar  sqljdbc4.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar             jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar     ojdbc7.jar                           parquet-format-2.0.0.jar    xz-1.5.jar
```

This is the connect string I am using:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pwd@server.company.com:1521:mydb
```

Should work.

Comment: I edited my reply when i noticed that an extra "!" was left after the "pwd". Yes my password ends with an "!" :(